Create JmsRecords for Java Unit testing
We are conducting Java unit testing and manipulating JmsRecord data. Not even sending or receiving data with JMS, conducting more data transformation.
Is there any available JmsRecord tool or testset from Apache, which allows to create JmsRecord in Java Unit Testing? The only data I'm really concerned is properties and text. We could use mocks, however there is lot of underneath methods which are being called, and could be somewhat hard.
The attempted code is pretty good, wondering if there is anything more optimal method.
Class Constructor Syntax:
public JmsRecord(
    @Nullable String jmsMessageID,
    long jmsTimestamp,
    String jmsCorrelationID,
    @Nullable Destination jmsReplyTo,
    Destination jmsDestination,
    int jmsDeliveryMode,
    boolean jmsRedelivered,
    String jmsType,
    long jmsExpiration,
    int jmsPriority,
    Map<String, Object> properties,
    String text) {

Object Declaration:
String jmsText = "abc";
Map<String,Object> jmsProperties = new HashMap(); 
jmsProperties.put("key", "test");

ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
Connection connection = activeMQConnectionFactory.createConnection();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
destination = session.createQueue("test.destination");

JmsRecord jmsRecord = new JmsRecord("A",
                                     1L, 
                                     null, 
                                     null, 
                                     destination,
                                     1, false,
                                     null, 
                                     2, 
                                     1 , 
                                     jmsProperties, 
                                     jmsText);

Resource:
How to mock connection factory in spring integration
